# How will I throw error in calculator using javascript? custom error not default errors?using exceptional handling

Tags: javascript, html, css

When user type wrong input than the custom error will generate and
    show error (you have typed wrong input)..I have create default error
    but not custom error.I need. I need custom error.Anyone help me

```js
var Scrn = document.querySelector('#screen');
var maibox = document.querySelector('.calBox');
var exp = '';
var errro_btn = document.querySelector('#error_screen');
var close = document.querySelector('#close')

maibox.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let vlu = e.target.value;

  if (vlu) {
    if (vlu != 'undefined') {
      if (vlu == '=') {
        try {


          exp = eval(exp)
          Scrn.innerHTML = exp
        } catch (error) {

          errro_btn.innerHTML += error.message
          errro_btn.style.display = "block"

        }
      } else if (vlu == 'ac') {
        Scrn.innerHTML = '0'
        exp = ''
      } else if (vlu == 'OFF') {
        Scrn.innerHTML = ''
        exp = ''
      } else if (vlu == 'undefined') {
        exp = '='
        Scrn.innerHTML = '0'
      } else if (vlu == '√') {
        exp = Math.sqrt(exp)
        Scrn.innerHTML += vlu
      } else if (vlu == '^') {
        exp = Math.pow(exp)
        Scrn.innerHTML = vlu
      } else if (vlu == 'sin') {
        exp = Math.sin(exp)
        Scrn.innerHTML = vlu
      } else if (vlu == 'cos') {
        exp = Math.cos(exp)
        Scrn.innerHTML = vlu
      } else if (vlu == 'tan') {
        exp = Math.tan(exp)
        Scrn.innerHTML = vlu
      } else {

        exp += vlu
        Scrn.innerHTML = exp
      }
    }
  }
})

errro_btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if (e.target.id === "close") {
    errro_btn.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
.calBox{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #767676,#767676,#767676, #aaa);
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px #8e8888 ;
}
span{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #bdcbbd;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 34px;
}
#error_screen{
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 380px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #D8000C;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #FFBABA;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

#close{
  padding:1px 5px 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #ffbaba;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #D8000C;
}
#close:focus{
  outline: none;
}

.buttons{
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#ac{
  background: #4D8C50;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 18px !important;
}
#oFF{
  padding: 10px 12px !important;
  background: #4D8C50;
}
#ans{
  background: #4D8C50;
}
button{
  padding: 10px 22px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px #9c9a9a;
  background: #454545;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calBox">

  <span id="screen">0</span>
  <span id="error_screen">
    <button id="close">x</button>
  </span>
  <hr>

  <button id="7" value='7'>7</button>
  <button id="8" value='8'>8</button>
  <button id="9" value='9'>9</button>
  <button id="ac" value='ac'>ac</button>
  <button id="oFF" value='OFF'>OFF</button>
  <button id="4" value='4'>4</button>
  <button id="5" value='5'>5</button>
  <button id="6" value='6'>6</button>
  <button id="del" value='del'>del</button>
  <button id="1" value='1'>1</button>
  <button id="2" value='2'>2</button>
  <button id="3" value='3'>3</button>
  <button id="+" value='+'>+</button>
  <button id="/" value='/'>/</button>
  <button id="0" value='0'>0</button>
  <button id="*" value='*'>x</button>
  <button id="." value='.'>.</button>
  <button id="-" value='-'>-</button>
  <button id="√" value='√'>√</button>

  <button id="sin" value='sin'>sin</button>
  <button id="cos" value='cos'>cos</button>
  <button id="tan" value='tan'>tan</button>
  <button id="ans" value='='>=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking about creating custom exception? because I don't see you generating any, you are just catching one.

Comment: Do you want to have an own exception type? Or do you just want to show an own message in case of an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is:

```
errro_btn.innerHTML+= error.message
```

Change this to:

```
errro_btn.innerHTML+= "Your custom error message here"
```

Below is working code snippet:

```js
var Scrn =document.querySelector('#screen');
var maibox = document.querySelector('.calBox');
var exp = '';
var errro_btn = document.querySelector('#error_screen');
var close = document.querySelector('#close')

maibox.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
 let vlu = e.target.value;

 if (vlu) {
  if (vlu != 'undefined'){
   if (vlu == '=') {
    try{
     

     exp=eval(exp)
     Scrn.innerHTML=exp
    }
    catch(error){

     errro_btn.innerHTML+= "Your custom error message"
     errro_btn.style.display="block"

    }
   }
   else if(vlu=='ac'){
    Scrn.innerHTML='0'
    exp=''
   }
   else if(vlu=='OFF'){
    Scrn.innerHTML=''
    exp=''
   }
   else if (vlu=='undefined'){
    exp='='
    Scrn.innerHTML='0'
   }
   else if(vlu=='√'){
    exp=Math.sqrt(exp)
    Scrn.innerHTML+=vlu
   }
   else if(vlu=='^'){
    exp=Math.pow(exp)
    Scrn.innerHTML=vlu
   }
   else if(vlu=='sin'){
    exp=Math.sin(exp)
    Scrn.innerHTML=vlu
   }
   else if(vlu=='cos'){
    exp=Math.cos(exp)
    Scrn.innerHTML=vlu
   }
   else if(vlu=='tan'){
    exp=Math.tan(exp)
    Scrn.innerHTML=vlu
   }
   else{

    exp+=vlu
    Scrn.innerHTML=exp
   }
  }
 }
})

errro_btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{

 if (e.target.id=== "close") {
        errro_btn.style.display = "none";
    } 
})
```

```css
.calBox{
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #767676,#767676,#767676, #aaa);
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px #8e8888 ;
}
span{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 380px;
 height: 38px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background: #bdcbbd;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 font-size: 34px;
}
#error_screen{
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 width: 380px;
 height: 34px;
 color: #D8000C;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background: #FFBABA;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-size: 16px; 
}

#close{
 padding:1px 5px 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #ffbaba;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #D8000C;
}
#close:focus{

 outline: none;

}
.buttons{
 margin-top: 40px;
}
#ac{
 background: #4D8C50;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px 18px !important;
}
#oFF{

 padding: 10px 12px !important;
 background: #4D8C50;

}
#ans{
 background: #4D8C50;
}
button{
 padding: 10px 22px;
 margin: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px #9c9a9a;
 background: #454545;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>calculator</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

 <div class="calBox">

  <span id="screen">0</span>
  <span id="error_screen">
   <button id="close">x</button>
  </span>
  <hr>



  <button id="7" value='7'>7</button>
  <button id="8" value='8'>8</button>
  <button id="9" value='9'>9</button>
  <button id="ac" value='ac'>ac</button>
  <button id="oFF" value='OFF'>OFF</button>
  <button id="4" value='4'>4</button>
  <button id="5" value='5'>5</button>
  <button id="6" value='6'>6</button>
  <button id="del" value='del'>del</button>
  <button id="1" value='1'>1</button>
  <button id="2" value='2'>2</button>
  <button id="3" value='3'>3</button>
  <button id="+" value='+'>+</button>
  <button id="/" value='/'>/</button>
  <button id="0" value='0'>0</button>
  <button id="*" value='*'>x</button>
  <button id="." value='.'>.</button>
  <button id="-" value='-'>-</button>
  <button id="√" value='√'>√</button>
  
  <button id="sin" value='sin'>sin</button>
  <button id="cos" value='cos'>cos</button>
  <button id="tan" value='tan'>tan</button>
  <button id="ans" value='='>=</button>
 </div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace **error.message** by your custom message.

```
errro_btn.innerHTML+= error.message
```

Becomes :

```
errro_btn.innerHTML += "Your custom message"
```

Comment: But that is just showing an error message. Isn't it about custom exceptions here? Maybe i get it wrong.

Comment: The author probably included "using exceptional handling" in the title of his subject because of the `try{ } catch(error){}` present in his code. I think he was just looking to edit the error message which is a default one.